# callback on .width()?

Tags: jquery, waitforimages

I'm setting a variable to the width of an image so that I can make a description div appear with the correct width. However, jQuery doesn't seem to have a callback function to suit my needs. What shall I do?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // declare photo width variable
    var photo_width = 0;
    $('.chImg').click(function () {
        // get img src and chop it up       
        var srcv = $(this).attr('src');
        var sliced = srcv.slice(6);
        // return the base number of the image for correspdonding div
        // corresponding div is "d#"
        var divnum = sliced.substring(0, sliced.length - 4);
        // fade out active description div
        $(".activeDescript").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("activeDescript");
            $(this).fadeOut(110);
        });
        // change picture
        $("#chBox").fadeOut(110, function () {
            $("#chBox").html("<center><img src='" + sliced + "'/></center>");
        });
        // vertical align
        $("#chBox").vAlign();
        $('#chBox').waitForImages(function () {
            // wait for images before grabbing img width
            $("#chBox img").each(function () {
                photo_width = $(this).width();
                $(".description").width(photo_width);
                $("#d" + divnum).fadeIn(300);
                // make this descript active
                $("#d" + divnum).addClass("activeDescript");
            });
            $("#chBox").fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
```

I'm mostly concerned with the code around photo_width = $(this).width(); as I want to ensure that the following code is executed AFTER that's happened.
Ideas?
I know that the description div is not being set properly because it takes 2 clicks to get it right! You can see the error at www.graysonearle.com/newtest and click on the first box "Frog Utopia" and click through a few thumbnails.

Comment: I don't get the problem. Everything after `photo_width = $(this).width();` IS executed after. This is not a non-blocking function call.

Comment: Must be something else then :/ Sorry. The problem can be seen here if you are interested: www.graysonearle.com/newtest if you click on the first box "Frog Utopia" and click on a few thumbnails.

Comment: You need to wait for the image to be loaded before you get it's width. Is the `waitForImages` method working properly? Where is that plugin located so we can see it?

Comment: http://graysonearle.com/newtest/js/waitforimages.js it seems to be working in another part of my code in which i wait for the images to load before implementing the lion bar plugin (for thumbnail scrollbars)

Comment: Although I just realized that I'm making a big assumption (new to jQuery) that if I loaded waitforimages.js in the page html, my imageswitch.js script (the code above) would use it automatically. Is there another way I have to include this in the .js script as well?